# rename keys from objects if they exist in dictionary (recursively)

Tags: typescript

(1) I have a simple dictionary as JS object.

```
const keys = {
  a: 'category',
  b: 'date',
  c: 'days',
} as const;
```

(2) I have a function which takes input data and renames all keys in found objects of input data. If a key exists in the dictionary relevant value will be used.

`const inputDataPassedToFunction = [{ a: 1, b: { c: [2], test: 3 } }] as const;`

(3) Expected result

```
readonly [{
    readonly category: 1;
    readonly date: {
        readonly days: readonly [2];
        readonly test: 3;
    };
}]
```

(4) Everything works but I have issues with TypeScript typings on line 31 of this file down below.

TS playground: https://tsplay.dev/WvEARm

Comment: Please place the text of your code directly in the question and not only as a link to an external site; it's great to have a Playground link as a supplement, but by itself doesn't count as being a [mre].  You should also explain exactly which error appears and where, directly in the question.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wy4Xdm) meet your needs? It seems the real question here has to do with indexed access types and not so much recursive dictionary stuff.  An actual minimal example could just be `interface Foo { a: "hey", b: "bee", c: "sea" } type Problem<T> = { [K in keyof T as Foo[K] extends string ? Foo[K] : K]: T[K] }`, with the same error.  And the solution looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4Oxem).  If you agree, could you replace your example with this one?

Comment: you are hero of mine :-) @jcalz

Comment: Thanks!  Could you address the content of my comments when you get a chance?

Comment: Yes, but how? @jcalz

Comment: I asked for information and for you to take several specific steps.  Is there a language barrier? If so, I'm sorry, but Stack Overflow depends on the ability of all parties to communicate effectively in English. If something I said doesn't make sense to you, could you ask me about it specifically?

Comment: @jcalz your second comment solved my issue... specially that link u shared w/ me

Comment: Part of the purpose of Stack Overflow is to allow future readers to search for and find existing questions whose answers help them.  So while it's great that you were personally helped, it would still be nice to think of those future readers.  Could you please [edit] your question as I requested, and I will post an answer? Or, if you don't want to do that, I can do it for you, with your permission.